# I just can't rig the shoulder well

Tags: rigging, armature

[image: arm raised]

[image: arm lowered]

I am a blender beginner and rigging a human model here starting by the A shape pose, but when I am doing the shoulder part I just can't make the gap disappears or make the mesh stretch like normal human muscle

Is there any way that can be done to deal with this situation?
I've tried weight paint but that doesn't works very well

Here is the blender file
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like part of your problem is where the bones are placed relative to the mesh; but without seeing a wireframe of the mesh it is hard to guess.  Could you add your blend file to your question?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: How did you create the bones? - It looks as if the upper arm bone isn't connected to the bone attached to the spine (clavicle). Normally you'd just extrude the upper arm bone from the inner bone and they'd automatically be joined. Also the shoulder joint looks to be too high. It should be roughly in the middle of the shoulder vertically.

Comment: I've uploaded a blender file of my mesh
I only use the human meta rig and adjust the positions of it and can't figure it out
Is it the topology of my mesh isnt right for the joints?

Answer (score 1):

Your rest pose is a A pose, it would probably have been better to use a T pose, but you could create 2 shape keys, the first one being the basis, the second being the deformed: Keep the second shapekey selected, raise the arm and use the sculpt tool to correct the shape of the shoulder. By the way, the fact that your body is a bit high-poly will make it a bit more difficult, is there a reason why you need it to be high-poly? Then use a driver so that when the arm bone rotates it triggers shape key #2, see tuto by Blender Secrets [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vJqAxPly3o).

[image]

[image]